# check how many document/envelope limit is left in my account

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

Is there an API call or somewhere in UI ,to check how many document limit is left in my account . I believe for sandbox or live account there is a limit on the number of documents you can send each month

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limit on the envelope count on the Sandbox account. But in Live the limit depends on the subscription you have done with DocuSign. If your subscription is envelope-based then you have a upper cap on the envelope count. I don't think there is any API call to know how many are left in your account, instead you should check with your DS Account Manager to know your upper cap limit and do the check on your code.

Comment: I have question regarding this.
My application is using "OAuth Authorization Code Grant" which redirects the user to authenticate with the DocuSign authentication service. DocuSign displays a login page. The end user logs in. This redirects the user back to my application and returns an authorization code to my application.

Now envelope is POSTED to clients account using API from my application. In this scenario , whose envelope limit gets applied ? Is it the user/clients account or my application account which I used for setting the integrator keys

Comment: It will be client's account who has authenticated themselves will be charged for envelopes. You account is like a Partner Account which is used for integration with DS. Once you got your clients' Access Token then you should create envelope on client's DS account. You will know client's DS Account or baseURI using /userinfo API call [UserInfo DS docs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/userinfo.html)

Comment: Thank you Amit . This answer is really helpful . Is there any special package I need to buy to be  Partner Account. In your first response u mentioned I need to check with DS Account Manager the upper cap limit and to check in code. What do I really check in code ?

Comment: When you are creating envelope from your code, save envelopeId and created datetime in you database. Once you know the upper cap for each of your client's account then put a check on your code to not create envelope if it has reached the envelope limit. If you do not want to use your DS Account for connection setup with your client, then you can request DS Account Manager to create a Partner Account for you which can be used for authenticating your client (using OAUTH) but cannot be used for sending envelope.